# Simple javascript search-and-replace

Tags: javascript

I know zero javascript, and have one simple task:

1. Find all text in the current html of the form [[.+?]]
2. Extract the content of the brackets
3. Replace all space characters with underscores
4. Instead of the entire expression, output `<img src="foo.com/$1.jpg"/>`, where $1 is the matched text (after spaces have been replaced).
5. (This should be done for all text inside [[]] in the html)

Can I bother you with a snippet that does this?

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yet? Give us some indication of effort here.

Comment: Well, I've _tried_ posting it to SO, but that didn't help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have the HTML source in a variable called `html`, you can do something like this:

```
var converted = html.replace(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g, function (s, token) {
    return '<img src="foo.com/'
        + token.split(" ").join("_")
        + '.jpg"/>';
});
```

To get or set the entire HTML inside `<body>`, you can use `document.body.innerHTML`. However, I would recommend specifically targeting elements of a certain id or class, if that string pattern doesn't really appear in random places in the page. I would also recommend that you use jQuery for locating these elements and changing their content:

```
$(".replacable").each(function () {
    this.html(imagize(this.html()));
});

function imagize(html) {
    return html.replace(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g, ...);
}
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me to run it only on certain elements and not the entire html